# How to get SelectdValue like a Simple Combobox but of datagridviewCombobox (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, desktop-application

How to get SelectdValue like a Simple Combobox but of datagridviewCombobox using row Index (dataGridView is Full) (VB.net)

I try a code, this works good but I don't now how to use it in Button Click event
The Code:

```vb
Private Sub dgvSampleList_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvSampleList.EditingControlShowing
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)

    If (comboBox IsNot Nothing) Then
        'Remove an existing event-handler
        RemoveHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)

        'Add the event handler. 
        AddHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    'Display selected value
    MsgBox("ProgramID: " & comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

this ComboBox Gets information from the database the Code:

```
fill.filldata_cb("fillDataProduct", Product_Name)
Product_Name.DisplayMember = "Product"
Product_Name.ValueMember = "ID"
```

The DataGridViewComboBox named Product_Name, I get data from db usig a Stored Procedure of SQL Server and function read the Stored Procedure and give the required parameters  .
Just I want to get value member related to the item selected in the DataGridViewComboBox

Comment: Not sure really understand.  The SelectedItem gives you the value.  Or you could check the value in the underlying data source of your datagridview.  Guessing you want to "name" your combo box at design time to a known value which will allow you to reference it from code withing the form?

Comment: Please use your eyes to look at the preview before posting your question and don't submit if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve rather than just how you're trying to achieve it. Your question doesn't actually make any sense because, if you're executing the `Click` event handler of a `Button`, there is no `ComboBox`. A `DataGridView` doesn't contain any child controls by default. When you edit a cell, an editing control is created and embedded in that cell specifically. That control is removed when the editing session ends. If you click a `Button`, the editing session will end automatically and the control will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

When you start editing a cell in a combo box column, the `Value` of the cell is assigned to the `SelectedValue` of the editing control and that sets the `SelectedItem`. When the editing session ends, the `SelectedValue` of the editing control is assigned back to the `Value` of the cell. There is no editing control in your case so there is no `SelectedValue` to get. You simply need to get the `Value` of the cell, just like any other cell.

In most cases, a combo box column will be bound to data from a database table, where there is an ID and a text name or description. If this data were bound to a standard `ComboBox` control, the name of the ID column would be assigned to the `ValueMember` and the name of the text column would be assigned to the `DisplayMember`. You generally do the same with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. The `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the column are then propagated to each cell and then to any editing controls embedded in those cells.

If you were using discrete controls to edit columns of a related table, you would bind the appropriate column of that data to the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox`. When you selected a record, the value from that column would be assigned to the `SelectedValue` and thus set the `SelectedItem` and any change made by the user would change the `SelectedValue` and that would be assigned back to the column of the child table. This is exactly how the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` works. The data from that child table is stored in the `Value` properties of the cells of the grid, so that's where the value you're interested in is stored.

EDIT:

Here is an example that demonstrates what is described above:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim parentTable As New DataTable

        With parentTable.Columns
            .Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("ParentName", GetType(String))
        End With

        With parentTable.Rows
            .Add(1, "Parent 1")
            .Add(2, "Parent 2")
            .Add(3, "Parent 3")
        End With

        parentBindingSource.DataSource = parentTable

        With parentColumn
            .DisplayMember = "ParentName"
            .ValueMember = "ParentId"
            .DataSource = parentTable
        End With

        Dim childTable As New DataTable

        With childTable.Columns
            .Add("ChildId", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("ChildName", GetType(String))
            .Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))
        End With

        With childTable.Rows
            .Add(1, "Child 1", 2)
            .Add(2, "Child 2", 3)
            .Add(3, "Child 3", 1)
        End With

        childBindingSource.DataSource = childTable
        childDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show(childDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value?.ToString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you run that code, select a cell in the combo box column and click the `Button` then the underlying ID for the cell will be displayed, rather than the text that's shown in the cell.

Here is the designer code file for the form I used in that example. You can just create a new form and paste in the designer code and user code from here and the form will be populated automatically. Note that you will need to click the *Show All Files* button in the *Solution Explorer* in order to access the designer code file.

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.childDataGridView = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
        Me.childBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.parentBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.IdColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.nameColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Me.parentColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        CType(Me.childDataGridView, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.childBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.parentBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'childDataGridView
        '
        Me.childDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
        Me.childDataGridView.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.IdColumn, Me.nameColumn, Me.parentColumn})
        Me.childDataGridView.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.childDataGridView.Name = "childDataGridView"
        Me.childDataGridView.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(389, 426)
        Me.childDataGridView.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(407, 12)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'IdColumn
        '
        Me.IdColumn.DataPropertyName = "ChildId"
        Me.IdColumn.HeaderText = "ID"
        Me.IdColumn.Name = "IdColumn"
        '
        'nameColumn
        '
        Me.nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "ChildName"
        Me.nameColumn.HeaderText = "Name"
        Me.nameColumn.Name = "nameColumn"
        '
        'parentColumn
        '
        Me.parentColumn.DataPropertyName = "ParentId"
        Me.parentColumn.HeaderText = "Parent"
        Me.parentColumn.Name = "parentColumn"
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.childDataGridView)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        CType(Me.childDataGridView, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.childBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.parentBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents childDataGridView As DataGridView
    Friend WithEvents childBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents parentBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents IdColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents nameColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents parentColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
End Class
```

Comment: when I get the of the cell, the program get the display text how can I fix that?

Comment: If you're saying what I think you're saying then you did it wrong. As you haven't bothered to show us what you did, there's no way for us to know what you did wrong. What you should have done was update your question and add the relevant new information in full. Regardless, I have updated my answer with an example that demonstrates exactly what I already described.

Comment: thank you I fix the problem I was use the dataGridView Like Invoice (No, Product Name, Quantity, Price, Total) I use ComboBox in the 'Product Name' Column for get products from database before that I use a Button Load only the existing Invoice This is what caused it